# Authentication failure with code 32

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi could someone help me with this?

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = '-'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

status = "Testing!"
api.update_status(status=status)
```

It gives me that error

> 'code': 32, 'message': 'Could not authenticate you.'

Comment: post the complete error stack please and please never post tokens - passwords and so on. I strongly recommend you go to your twitter account and reset the tokens you provided the whole community

Comment: Change your tokens!

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with your code, this is an authentication issue. Please refer to https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

> Code: 32
>
> Text: Could not authenticate you
>
> Description: Your call could not be completed as dialed.

On Twitter's developer forum there is a thread on this [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/errors-message-could-not-authenticate-you-code-32/1223/4) . You should probably check this with Twitter.

Answer (score 6):

1. Be sure that you are using correct `ACCESS_TOKEN` `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET`.
2. If you are copy-pasting your credentials then check leading and trailing white spaces.(In most of my cases)
3. Sometimes it might be possible that your `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` are Expired, so regenerate them and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have forgot to click button "create my Access Token" on the bottom of "keys and access tokens" of **Twitter Application Management**.

Answer (score 1):

Usual problem with twitter API is that if you have recently changed the permissions for your app, you will have to  re-generate your OAUTH keys

Answer (score 1):

In case of Jupyter Notebook, if you are executing the following first,

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

and then if you are running next snippet

```
status = "Testing!"
api.update_status(status=status)
```

you are likely to get Error 32, 
Try running the entire block of code and be sure to check the spaces after the token and keys

Comment: This works. Separation of the auth instance from the api instance seemed to be the cause of the error.   Running it in one block of code does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Triple check the way you are feeding your tokens**

The problem for me was one of those stupid mistakes programmers sometimes make and that take hours to debug...
I was feeding the tokens via a document and for each line I was cropping the last character (line break = "\n"). As the document ended in the last character of the token from the last user, every time I tried to Log him in, the error 32 showed up because the last character of the last token was missing. Adding a new line in the end of the document fixed the issue.

**Moral of the story:** Check the way you are feeding the token to the API and look for some simple yet fatal error

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I would randomly get this error until I realized it was related to the way I was encoding my status text in the url—it had (almost) nothing to do with my OAuth headers which were basically correct.

Everything worked smoothly once I converted the status text into a form parameter. I suspect this issue was compounded by the fact my oauth library (npm package `oauth-1a`) consumes the url along with the status text and possibly encodes it differently using a function like `encodeURI()`.

`Node.js` psuedocode below,

```
// Create authorization header using oauth library
const oauthHeader = ...

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('status', 'Messy status text with spaces');

fetch(
  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',  // No status text in url
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      ...oauthHeader
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem probably happened because your ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET were created with read-only permissions. You must return to "Settings" to "App permissions" and edit to "Read and Write" or "Read and Write and Direct Messages" and then regenerate your ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).